# Email Sign in link - web client JavaScript | Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a web-app that uses Firebase (web client JavaScript). For authentication, I am trying to implement **sendSignInLinkToEmail** to sign in a user. But, I’m facing an issue.

Suppose the user is trying to login on his desktop and uses his phone for verification, I want to redirect him to the dashboard on the desktop after verification. How can I do this?

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

```js
const actionCodeSettings = { url: 'dashboardURL', handleCodeInApp: true }
```

This redirects to the `dashboardURL` on the phone (device used for verification), but I want to redirect on the desktop (device that initiated the login flow).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication does not natively support this. You'll be logged in on the device where you open the link. You'll have to build this functionality yourself and a simpler approach would be to use Cloud Functions and Realtime Database.

The flow would be like:

1. User clicks on "send link" and is redirected to a page that listens for updates in realtime database at a key (randomly generated session ID depending on your requirements).
2. When a logs in on another device, call a Cloud Function that generates a [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for signing in and then emit it the first device via realtime database.
3. Log the user in with `signInWithCustomToken()`.

This is just a simplified version of a system that might use websockets, session Ids and additional factors for security. You can also use Firebase Anonymous authentication to ensure only that user can this token using security rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dharmraj. I had thought of a workaround involving the database. But, I was looking if there was a simple solution, using Firebase state values/deep links in email. Thanks for the clarification and your time :)